# lista com valores maiores que o informado pelo usuariao

Tags: lista, pandas

Preciso de um programa que imprima uma lista com valores maiores que o informado pelo usuário, sendo que estes valores que precisam ser impressos pela lista estão em uma função já definida.
Meu código:

```
import pandas as pd

dados = pd.read_csv('./DadosClimaticos2018Londrina.csv', sep = ';', parse_dates = ['Data'])
dados['Mes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dados['Data'], yearfirst = True).month

# FUNÇÕES
def um(temp):
    return pd.DataFrame(temp.groupby('Mes')['Temperatura'].mean()).reset_index()

listaTM = []
tmmin = float(input('Digite a temperatura media minima: '))  
listaTM.append(tmmin)
print(listaTM)
```

Answer (score 0):

Importando o pacote:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Carregando os dados e criando uma nova coluna:

```
dados = dados = pd.read_csv('./DadosClimaticos2018Londrina.csv', sep = ';', parse_dates = ['Data']) 
dados['Mes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dados['Data'], yearfirst = True).month
```

Função que retorna as médias da temperatura por mês:

```
def um(temp): 
    return pd.DataFrame(temp.groupby('Mes')['Temperatura'].mean()).reset_index()
```

Recebendo o valor mínimo do usuário:

```
tmmin = float(input('Digite a temperatura media minima: '))
```

Função que retorna as temperaturas maiores que o filtro:

```
def um_filtro(temp, tem_min):
    temp1 = um(temp)
    return temp1[temp1['Temperatura'] > tem_min]
```

*Aproveitamos a função de média e chamamos ela dentro da função filtro.*

---

Chamando a função e passando os valores:

```
um_filtro(dados,tmmin)
```

Saída:

```
    Mes     Temperatura
0     1     24.763441
2     3     24.776344
3     4     24.008889
10   11     24.653333
11   12     26.073118
```